# Variable saved after exiting Powerapps

Tags: powerapps

I want my global variable to be saved on all systems and even after exiting it should still be there, is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in fact there some many ways of doing that.

You will need a database/datasource in order to store those values. For example, you will have a SharePoint List and you will save those variables values in that list.

Then, once you start you app, you retrieve those values from the datasource, likely using [LookUp or Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-filter-lookup) functions.

[This Formula Reference doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/formula-reference) is really good to find all Power Apps formulas with examples and videos.

SharePoint as a datasource is just an example of a way to keep your app "free". If you need a different source (SQL, Oracle, Dataverse, ...), you might be looking at a Premium App, requiring users to have licenses to use that app.

Another approach would be using SaveData and LoadData. Example:

```
SaveData( LocalCache, "MyCache" )
LoadData( LocalCache, "MyCache" )
```

Note that this functions are currently in the "Experimental Features" for web browser, but should be fully functional if using in mobile phones.
Also, ***this feature is disabled by default. To enable, navigate to Settings > Upcoming features > Experimental > Enabled SaveData, LoadData, ClearData on web player." and turn the switch on.***

Comment: Thanks for your answere, My powerapp already has shairpoint connected how do I put my variable value in the shairpoint list and call it up again. would you have an example code?